# Excel Links(With some bloomberg function as input) not updated until VBA finished

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I have an excel input workbook A has some inputs based on internal worksheets references and bloomberg function plus some calculation fields.

I have an excel output workbook B that needs to retrieve the information from A, however, if I I open workbook A within B's vba, it wont update the links infor until the VBA finish calling.

example of A's input, A contains sheet1, sheet2, sheet3
        I want a cells from sheet1 cells(1,1), the content of cells(1,1) mite be sheets2!cells(2,1), this sheets2!cells(2,1) mite be a calculation field based on reference from another tab or some bloomberg function call input.

Is there way that I can validate all the links within workbook A first, so that my workbook B could retrieve all the updated information.

I have tried

```
Application.Workbooks.Open FileName:=path_array(tmp), UpdateLinks:=3       
Application.Calculate
Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval = 0
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
Application.Run "ConnectChartEvents"
Application.Run "RefreshData"
Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkBook"
DoEvents

VBA Output looks like this:
A      B      C  D  E   F   G   H   I   J
4.4%  2.1%  2.2%    #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! 11  5   #VALUE!
Manual like this:
A      B      C  D  E   F   G   H   I   J
4.4%  2.1%  2.2%    3.1%    4.2%    5.5%    3.4%    11  5   8.0%
```

to force some of the calculation go thru, its updating using VBA but will return #Value! for the fields that have extra layer of reference. If I open it just manually, everything auto updated less than a second. Have been struggling why there are such difference. Is there way that I clock VBA until this input is updated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `DoEvents`?

Comment: Nope, will that help? The big confusion I am getting is why there is a difference betweeen manual and vba automated open it. I will give a try

Comment: Hi RBarryYoung, tried DoEvents, no luck :(

Comment: Hmm, it's probably updating asynchronously and just takes a few seconds to finish and recalculate.

Comment: Hi RBarryYoung, do u know if there is way that I can force it back to synchronously when using VBA

Comment: No, I've only used Bloomberg once.  I'd check the Bloomberg tab though to see if there are any options like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, hopefully I can figure out :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bloomberg data doesn't populate until Excel VBA macro finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669845/bloomberg-data-doesnt-populate-until-excel-vba-macro-finishes)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with bloomberg but here are three things.

You can delay execution in workbook B with [Application.OnTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165(v=office.14).aspx). Load workbook A, then call a second sub in workbook B using Application.OnTime with a second or two delay, this should allow workbook A to run whatever code it runs on loading.

[Application.RTD.RefreshData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194391(v=office.14).aspx) might help.

More specific to your question, do the answers here help?
[How to refresh/load RTD Bloomberg function (BDH) in excel in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856979/how-to-refresh-load-rtd-bloomberg-function-bdh-in-excel-in-vba)

Comment: Hi AndASM, thanks for the reply. The problem is the input workbook A, when manual open it, it takes less than a sec to update. When  open it from workbook B uisng vba, put a on.time 2 seconds delay, its not updating. only after the vba finishes.

Comment: @YoYue Your best bet is probably to retrieve the data using the VBA API rather than formulae. The formulae won't update as long as your VBA code is running I think.

Comment: @assylias the problem is that I dont own that input sheet, the mapping logic is really messy with 20+ worksheets workbook. If I repopulate everything into VBA API, thats not sth doable in a short time period. Do u know if there is any workaround of this. you are probly right, the formula update is served as whenever the excel is free or update every 2 seconds by default, if currently VBA is running the formula will frozen and wait until the current excel is finished. I am assuming there exist a bloomberg function that can force such an update occurs