# VBA/Bloomberg : how to declare BloombergUi

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I declared all the variables on my code, I can't understand why I have this type of errror :

[image]

[image]

My code is :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Code_Isin()
    Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
    Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim ws As Object
    Dim Num_Ligne As Long
    Dim BloombergUI As Object

    For Each ws In Worksheets
    
    Num_Ligne = 2
       
        xlCalc = Application.Calculation
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            While ws.Cells(Num_Ligne, 1) <> ""
                ws.Cells(Num_Ligne, 2).Formula = "=BDP(""" & ws.Cells(Num_Ligne, 1).Value & "Equity"" , ""NAME"")"
                BloombergUI.RefreshAllStaticData
                Num_Ligne = Num_Ligne + 1
            Wend
            
            Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
            Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to `Set` BloombergUI to something valid before you can use it.  Right now it is `Nothing`.

Comment: @BrianMStafford thank you, do yo have the example of code, please ? I can't find it on Internet

Comment: BloombergUI is not an `Object` it is an add in. Maybe this will help solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856979/how-to-refresh-load-rtd-bloomberg-function-bdh-in-excel-in-vba

Comment: @Marie I'm afraid I know nothing about Bloomberg.  However, there are a number of questions on this site that may be helpful to you, including the link from Kevin.